# Split/Parse Values in One Column and create multiple Columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, split

I have a column in which multiple fields are concatenated, they are delimited by . and :
Example: `Order ID:0001ACW120I .Record ID:01160000000UAxCCW .Type:Small .Amount:4596.35  .Booked Date 2021-06-14`

I have tried the following:

```
df["Details"].str.split(r" .|:", expand=True)
```

But I lose the Decimal and the Amount doesn't Match.

I want to parse the Details Column to:
|Details                                                |Order ID   |Record ID      |Type   |Amount     |Booked Date    |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|-----------------------|-------|---------------|---------------|
|Order ID:0001ACW120I .Record ID:01160000000UAxCCW .Type:Small .Amount:4596.35  .Booked Date 2021-06-14 |0001ACW120I    |01160000000UAxCCW  |Small  |4596.35    |2021-06-14 |

Thank you for your help and guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will give you the solution you want.

Original Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Order ID:0001ACW120I .Record ID:01160000000UAxCCW .Type:Small .Amount:4596.35  .Booked Date 2021-06-14']})
```

Replacing `.` with `:` & then splitting with `:`

```
df = df['A'].replace(to_replace ='\s[.]', value = ':', regex = True).str.split(':', expand = True)
```

Final dataset. Rename the columns.

```
print(df)
```